# How to create magento 2 theme and module manually?

Tags: magento2

I'm new to magento2 and I don't know how to use theme and module manually, please guide me

Comment: Please follow some tutorials. When you face any issues, come back with that along with what you've tried. This is not the right place to look for tutorials. :)

Comment: The Magento DevDocs should have the information you need to get started. 

How to create a theme
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

How to create a module:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/build.html